# Exist script when any command fails

Tags: shell

I have a large shell script that install a bunch of stuff. 9/10 times, it will work fine, however, it sometimes fails due to internet connectivity issues.

currently I have

```
apt-get install -y apache2 || { exit 1; }
```

and it works.

and I know that `!!` resembles the last command.

However, this does not work

```
apt-get install -y apache2 || { echo "!! Failed"; exit 1; }
```

I would expect the output, if failed, be:

```
apt-get install -y apache2 Failed
```

lastly, is there a way not to have the `|| { echo "!! Failed"; exit 1; }` after every command.

Comment: I guess it would be `echo !! "Failed"`. But `!!` will track the previous last command, not the one you just did before the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, say

```
set -e
# some arbitrary command
apt-get install -y apache2
# more commands
```

This would make the script exit if any subsequent command returns with non-zero exit code and would obviate the need of placing `|| exit` besides every command in your script.

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> -e
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single simple command (see Simple Commands), a subshell command
>   enclosed in parentheses (see Command Grouping), or one of the commands
>   executed as part of a command list enclosed by braces (see Command
>   Grouping) returns a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the
>   command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a
>   while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of
>   any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following
>   the final `&&` or `||`, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the
>   command’s return status is being inverted with `!`. A trap on `ERR`, if
>   set, is executed before the shell exits.
>
> This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell
>   environment separately (see Command Execution Environment), and may
>   cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the
>   subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/bash-echoing-the-last-command-run), the following will work for BASH (and perhaps other shells as well):

```
trap 'previous_command=$this_command; this_command=$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
trap 'if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "$previous_command Failed"; fi' EXIT
set -e
```

Alternatively, you could use the built-in tracing, but this will print every command, not just the one that failed:

```
set -ex
```