# cp exits with a 64 error status

Tags: bash, packagemaker

I am using a preflight bash script in **packagemaker** :

`run cp -pf "/folder/to/my/db" "/Library/Application Support/app/db`

The run function (that I found on StackOverflow by the way) :

`run() { $*; code=$?; [ $code -ne 0 ] && echo "command [$*] failed with error code $code\nERROR: $@\n"; }`

The command `cp` returns a 64 code. What is this 64 status please?
How can I resolve that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please identify where you found the `run` function on SO so that we can go and fix it.  And I'm sorry you got misled by a bogus (or partly bogus) answer elsewhere.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/bash-echoing-the-last-command-run)

Comment: OK: I'd just found [Bash: echoing the last command run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/bash-echoing-the-last-command-run) as a possibility too, and was coming back to ask.  I will go perform surgery. _[…time passeth…]_ Surgery performed.  +1 for researching on SO, and for allowing us to fix a problem.

Comment: this website is amazing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a folder `Support/app/db` for the command to copy files `/folder/to/my/db` and `/Library/Application` to.

Replace the misguided (almost always wrong) `$*` with the correct `"$@"`:

```
run()
{
    "$@"
    code=$?
    [ $code -ne 0 ] && echo "command [$*] failed with error code $code\nERROR: $@\n"
}
```

Plain `$*` breaks words at spaces; `"$@"` preserves spaces in arguments.  Most often, `$*` is not the right notation (though it would be fine in the `echo` where you used `$@`).  It isn't clear to me why the command's arguments are being listed twice in the error message.

---

The error reporting would be improved by adding `>&2` to the end to redirect the output to standard error, which is where error messages belong.  (I'd remove the repetition while I'm at it.)  Note that using `$*` inside the argument to `echo` is entirely appropriate.

```
    [ $code -ne 0 ] && echo "command [$*] failed with error code $code" >&2
```

In fact, the `run()` function can be simplified still more; the variable `code` really isn't needed:

```
run()
{
    "$@" || echo "command [$*] failed with error code $?" >&2
}
```

If you want the script to exit too, then you can use:

```
run()
{
    "$@" || { echo "command [$*] failed with error code $?" >&2; exit 1; }
}
```

The `{ ...; }` notation treats the commands within as a unit for I/O redirection without starting a sub-shell.

---

See also [How to iterate over arguments in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script/256225#256225).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. I don't have anymore error ! However the cp still does not work… Nothing is copied.

Comment: My bad I forgot those stupid quotes around $@ ! Thank you very much for your quick answer Jonathan

Comment: I think that the correct term for 'those stupid quotes' is actually 'those all-important double quotes'.  Plain `$*` and `$@` behave the same; `"$*"` and `"$@"` are both different from each other and different from the unquoted versions.