# BASH: special parameter for the last command, not parameter, executed

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am looking for a workaround for processes with a long duration.
There is the special parameter $_ containing the last parameter of the last command.
Well I am asking you for something vice versa.

For example:

```
/etc/init.d/service stop; /etc/init.d/service start
```

.. could be easier if there is a parameter/variable containing the last binary/script called. Let's define it as `$.` and we get this:

```
/etc/init.d/service stop; $. start
```

Do you have any Idea how to get this?
I found this [Thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6110446/4091332)
But I only get output like this:
`printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"`

But the var $BASH_COMMAND is working well:

```
# echo $BASH_COMMAND
echo $BASH_COMMAND

# echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.2(1)-release
```

Any help is very appreciated!
Thank you,
Florian

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4009451/1096140

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't fit my needs, because the history expansion is going to expand too early. And the !:1 meets the last used parameter not command. Here is my try: 

`{root@redmine-dev01.kvbb.lan} /root/tmp

# ls -l
insgesamt 0

{root@redmine-dev01.kvbb.lan} /root/tmp
# /etc/init.d/httpd stop; !:1
/etc/init.d/httpd stop; -l
httpd beenden:                                             [FEHLGESCHLAGEN]
-bash: -l: command not found`


edit:/ how do I get a \n here?

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice you want the 2 commands in the same line! As you said, this won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the primary problem is the duration of the first process, and you know what the next process will be, you can simply issue a wait command against the first process and follow it with the second.

Example with backgrounded process:

```
./longprocess &
wait ${!}; ./nextprocess # ${!} simply pulls the PID of the last bg process
```

Example with manual PID entry:

```
./longprocess
# determine PID of longprocess
wait [PID]; ./nextprocess
```

Or, if it is always start|stop of init scripts, could make a custom script like below.

```
#/bin/bash
#wrapperscript.sh
BASESCRIPT=${1}
./$BASESCRIPT stop
./$BASESCRIPT start
```

Since the commands are wrapped in a shellscript, the default behavior will be for the shell to wait for each command to complete before moving on to the next. So, execution would look like:

```
./wrapperscript.sh /etc/init.d/service
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-execute the last command by using:

```
!!
```

however, this won't help with what you want to do, so you could try using the "search and replace on last command" shortcut:

```
^<text to search for>^<text to replace with>^
```

so your problem could be solved using:

```
/etc/init.d/service stop; ^stop^start^
```

**NOTE:** This will only replace the **first** instance of the search text.

Also, see the comments below by more experienced peeps, for other examples and useful sources.

Comment: +1 Note that `^stop^start` is a shortcut for `!!:s/stop/start/`; there is a wealth of operators you can apply to history expansions, of which `!!` is just one example.

Comment: @chepner - yup, absolutely. Also, by that token `^foo^bar^` will only replace the **first** occurrence of the search term, but it's a nice and short, err, shortcut =)

Comment: `!!:0` (or `!:0`) gives you the command word from the previous command -- see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Designators