# How to read the last executed command comment (after #) in bash?

Tags: bash

I know there are some bash variables that are assigned after executing a Bash command. Some of them are `$?` to get the return value of the process or `$BASH_COMMAND` to get the actual call line, `$1`, `$2` etc to retrieve the call args, etc.

A simple trick with trap would (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/bash-echoing-the-last-command-run)) allow me to store the last executed command:

```
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ trap 'previous_command=$this_command; this_command=$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ ls -l #I want to read this comment
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alariva alariva 0 Aug 23 01:30 readme.md
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ echo $previous_command
ls -l
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ echo $?
0
```

I need to get the comment that may come after the last command, but I'm not aware of any variable that would store it. Is there any way to read it?

I would like to get a similar behavior to this:

```
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ ls -l #I want this comment
readme.md
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ echo $BASH_COMMENT
I want this comment
alariva@trinsic:~/test$
```

Of course, the current situation is that I cannot retrieve any info from this:

```
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ echo $BASH_COMMENT

alariva@trinsic:~/test$
```

I'm also aware that comments may be completely stripped out after Bash interprets the call, so in that case I wonder if there exists a workaround (like a hook or something) to read it before it actually reaches bash.

---

So far, this is what I achieved:

```
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ ls -l #tosto
total 0
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ LAST=`fc -l | cut -c 6- | tail -n2 | head -n1`
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ echo "${LAST##*\#}"
tosto
alariva@trinsic:~/test$
```

Not sure if this is the best possible solution and if it'd work on all scenarios but looks like the behavior I want to achieve. Is there any built-in/alternative way to get this?

Comment: There's nothing Linux-specific here, removed the tag. Please read the tags' descriptions before applying them.

Comment: `ls -l # comment` then `history | tail -1`

Comment: Looks like near the way. I will try what happens and update as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest solution I came up so far is the following.

```
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ ls -l #tosto
total 0
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ LAST=`fc -l | cut -c 6- | tail -n2 | head -n1`
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ echo "${LAST##*\#}"
tosto
alariva@trinsic:~/test$
```

While that will work for most of the scenarios I use, it still will fail to get the full comment on some scenarios where more than one `#` is found:

```
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ ls -l #tosto #only partial
total 0
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ LAST=`fc -l | cut -c 6- | tail -n2 | head -n1`
alariva@trinsic:~/test$ echo "${LAST##*\#}"
only partial
alariva@trinsic:~/test$
```

Improvements on this answer are welcome.