# Save all 'ssh' commands to a file

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, prompt

I log into a lot of servers via `ssh`. Typically I just use the easy `bash` [history search](https://gist.github.com/snipe/5405846) to scroll through my history of 'ssh' commands and find the one I want. However, eventually my `.bash_history` reaches its limit and I start losing entries, despite increasing the limits, etc..

I would rather just adjust my `$PROMPT_COMMAND` so that after every command, it checks to see if I ran a command with `ssh`, and if so, appends that command to a file somewhere.

I saw some relevant questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/bash-echoing-the-last-command-run) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212872/how-to-get-last-n-commands-from-history) but I am struggling to understand how to use these in a function that I can source from my `.bashrc` and add to my `$PROMPT_COMMAND` that will check if the last command entered started with `ssh` and copy it to a file.

For example, this does not work:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND="echo; foo; "
$ foo () { echo "command was: $BASH_COMMAND" ; }
$ ssh cn-0030
...(Ctrl-D)...
$ logout
Connection to cn-0030 closed.

command was: echo "command was: $BASH_COMMAND"
```

This also does not work:

```
$ foo () { echo !! | grep ssh --color ; }
```

Because `!!` gets expanded into the actual last command run immediately and then saved into `foo`, instead of being evaluated when `foo` is evaluated

Comment: but why you don't store all your ssh in .ssh directory config file, isn't better?

Comment: You might want to spend some time perusing `man ssh_config`, especially the `Host`, `User`, and `RemoteCommand` keywords. You may not need to use shell history as much as you think.

Comment: Another thought is use another command to ssh (I called mine `go2`) then write that script to enable any smarts you want like auto-completion, history, etc ....

Comment: You also might consider adding `history -w` to `foo()` which will save your commands to the .bash_history.