# Unable to echo last executed within .sh script

Tags: bash, scripting, sh, command-substitution

Using following on

> cmd=$(uname -a)
>
> printf "["!:0"]"

gives me

```
[cmd1=Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-300.10.1.el5uek #1 SMP Wed Feb 22 17:37:40 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux]
```

but when is done in `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(uname -a)


printf "["!:0"]"
```

I'm getting

`[!:0]`

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do but the history of commands is not mantained in scripts, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502698/2290372.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the previous command executed inside a bash (`v4+`) script,

```
#!/bin/bash -i
# -i: interactive mode, enable history inside script
set -o history  # enable history, for old bash versions

cmd=$(uname -a)
history | sed -n 'x;${s/ *[0-9]\+ *\(\S*\)/\1/p}'  # print the line before last history entry after removing index
```

Comment: Try adding `set -o history`. See the updated answer.