# Bash's $_ variable not expanding

Tags: bash

The `$_` variable, which should expand with the arguments of the last executed command in Bash, contains `_lp_runtime_before`. No matter how many times I run a command, that would be the content it has. Why?

Comment: Show us the whole script how you are using it, we need a minimal reproducible example to re-create your problem

Comment: Note that `$_` is an interactive feature -- not guaranteed to be available in scripts -- and further, that many shell-builtin variables are defined to lose their special behavior should anything assign to them explicitly.

Comment: So this is more a [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) question.

Comment: `$_` is a [special parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) that behaves the same in both interactive and non-interactive shells.

Comment: I would like to do any simple thing like `$ mkdir foo; cd $_`

Comment: I recreated the question there. Link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548630/bashs-var-not-expanding

Comment: @NicoRodsevich and slightly modifed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $_ expand to the **last argument** of the last command line, according to the man page of `bash`:

> [$_] expands to the last argument to the previous command, after expansion.

If you want the whole arguments, [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502698/4375327) `!:*`:

```
$ ls -a -l -h test
[blah blah]
$ last_command="!:*" > /dev/null

$ echo $last_command
-a -l -h test
```

I added a redirection of `stdout` to null device to prevent bash to print the expansion.

Comment: History expansion is typically off-topic here: SO is only for questions about writing software, and history expansion is only enabled by default in interactive shells (as opposed to those executing scripts).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, TIL about expansion enabling and executing scripts.