# Execute last command in iTerm2

Tags: iterm2

To execute the last command in iTerm2, I can do:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>

How can I do a shortcut to execute this? When I try doing a remap "send text" it only sends the literal text:

```
$ <C-p><Return>
```

What would be proper way to execute the last command?

Comment: `!!<return>` runs the last command. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502698

Comment: @zedfoxus right, but how to execute that in a shortcut I mean?

Comment: @zedfoxus in the above it would be "Send Hex Code" `0x21 0x21 0x0d` for !![return] but sending the text by itself wouldn't actually execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter in the hex codes for the two keystrokes,  and :

[image]

You will need to look up the hex codes for each character, for example, using [`xxd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd).

```
$ # enter xxd in 'raw' mode, ctrl-v to send key; ctrl-d to send EOF/exit
$ xxd
^P^M
00000000: 100d 0a
```