# $BASH_COMMAND is overwritten too early in Trap DEBUG

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have

```
trap 'python my_script.py --command \"$BASH_COMMAND\"' DEBUG
```

my_script.py is

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--command', default="")
args = parser.parse_args()

command = args.command

print("COMMAND", command)
```

But when I run a bash command the output is

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='python my_script.py'
```

Rather than the command that was run that triggered the trap.

How can I get the initial run command from my_script.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BASH_COMMAND` is **currently** executed command. So as you found out, the current program at `python my_script.py` is that script and that's what is in `BASH_COMMAND`.

Cache the current value of `BASH_COMMAND` and execute your script for the previous value that was in `BASH_COMMAND`. From [Echoing the last command run in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/echoing-the-last-command-run-in-bash) .

```
trap 'prev_bash_command=$BASH_COMMAND; python my_script.py --command \"$prev_bash_command\"' DEBUG
```