# Expand Last Command in Conditional Statement

Tags: bash

I'm trying to solve a very mundane problem. I want PS1 to change depending upon the previous command executed. Whether success or failure isn't the issue here. I want PS1 to include `\w`, but only if the last command entered was `cd`. What I have at the moment is:

```
if [[ !:0 == "cd" ]]
then
   PS1='(\w)[jobs: \j] > '
else
   PS1='[jobs: \j] > '
```

The output will always be the shorter one, regardless of the last command.

I feel like I'm making a simple mistake somewhere, and this also seems mundane enough that I can't find anything related through Google.

Comment: So only `cd` and nothing else, no arguments?

Comment: I would expect arguments, but I thought !:0 was specifically the command (and !:1 the first argument, and so on)

Comment: Ah, your'e trying to use history expansion?

Comment: I am, and unless there's a particular usage constraint on history expansion I'm not sure why it doesn't work. I admit, I've never tried to use it in this context before.

Comment: I have disabled history expansion eons ago in my ~/.bashrc file, :-)

Comment: Oh, maybe it's disabled by default? This is a new installation and I'd never thought about it. Why do you have them disabled?

Comment: I don't do `!!` in an interactive session, but afaik history expansion is enable by default

Comment: What about other commands (besides `cd`) which change the working directory? Perhaps what you need is to _detect a change in the working directory_, irrespective which command was causing it?

Comment: @Jetchisel Thanks to you I learned a new thing about .bashrc. : ) I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user1934428 I think you're right. It started as a little throwaway QoL change, but now it's become an obsession, as these things tend to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in `.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='
if [[ "$NEWPWD" != "$PWD" ]]; then
    PS1="(\w)[jobs: \j] > "
    NEWPWD=$PWD
else
    PS1="[jobs: \j] > "
fi'
```

You can use whichever name you want for `$NEWPWD`

It's simple, it works, and is not prone to errors.

Comment: I like that a lot, thank you! I kicked around the idea of a variable, but I dismissed it as too resource-intensive. I guess that really hasn't been an issue in decades. :-) This is really straightforward, thank you.

Comment: It seemed like it was working, but for some reason it's now only ever outputting the long prompt, regardless of the state of $NEWPWD. `echo $NEWPWD` and `echo $PWD` have the same value, but the shorter prompt is still missing.

Comment: It's working here. Probably ask a new question where you debug it with `set -x` if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Probably [avoid upper case for your private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) though.

Comment: Fair points. Thank you, I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I'm speculating that this might very well be related to something else interfering with your `PROMPT_COMMAND` in interesting ways, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Upvoted; added a variation of this in my answer, too

Comment: SOLVED. It was a rookie mistake. I had a single-quote/double-quote conflict. For some reason I didn't get the usual syntax error, but that's a separate problem. Marked solved, thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

The Csh-style `!:0` history expansion is an interactive feature. You can use the command `history -p "!:0"` to execute it in a script context, though (even when you have `set +H`, like most sane people have); but executing it inside `PROMPT_COMMAND` or the prompt itself is highly unwieldy. (When I tried, it would show me the *penultimate* command, or something from within the `PROMPT_COMMAND` scriptlet itself.)

Borrowing from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6110446/874188 (currently the accepted answer to [Echoing the last command run in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6109225/874188)) I would go with

```sh
trap 'prompt_previous_command=$prompt_this_command; prompt_this_command=$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
PS1='$([[ ${prompt_previous_command%%\ *} == "cd" ]] && echo "(${PWD/$HOME/~})")[jobs: \j] \> '
```

It is unfortunate that `echo "\\w"` doesn't produce the *expanded* value in this context; `${PWD/$HOME/~}` is a reasonable approximation, although there are corner cases where it gets it wrong.

... Perhaps a less confusing approach is to set the value in the trap already:

```sh
trap 'prompt_previous_command=$prompt_this_command
      prompt_this_command=$BASH_COMMAND
      [[ "${prompt_previous_command%%\ *}" == "cd" ]] &&
          prompt_cwd="(\\w)" || prompt_cwd=""
    PS1="$prompt_cwd[jobs: \\j] \\> "' DEBUG
```

Many Bash add-ons want to hook into your `PROMPT_COMMAND` and might sabotage any attempt to reserve it for youself; of course, this approach has a similar problem if you have something else in your system which relies on the `DEBUG` trap for something.

To make this work for `pushd` / `popd` and aliases etc too, here's an adaptation of Dan's excellent answer:

```sh
trap 'case ${prompt_prev_pwd-$PWD} in
       "$PWD") PS1="[jobs \\j] > ";;
       *) PS1="(\\w)[jobs: \\j] > ";;
      esac
      prompt_prev_pwd=$PWD' DEBUG
```

Comment: I hadn't seen that Q/A before. There's a lot of good info there. I'm not too familiar with using bash debug beyond the basic troubleshooting stuff, so this was definitely helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On approach is to create a function and parse `history`. The `PROMPT_COMMAND` is also needed.

Put the code below in your `~/.bashrc` file or put it in another file, just make sure you source that file from `~/.bashrc`

```
is_cd(){
  set -- $(history 1)
  if [[ $2 == "cd" ]]; then 
   echo cd_is_the_last_command
  else
    echo no_cd
  fi
}

if [[ $PROMPT_COMMAND != *is_cd* ]]; then
   PROMPT_COMMAND="is_cd"
fi
```

---

- Change the lines with `echo`'s with the actual command you want to execute.
- Source `~/.bashrc` after you have edited it.
- This assumes that the output of your history has the numeric number first and command as the second column.

Comment: The regex should be anchored; as currently posted, it will match on `"echo acdc"`

Comment: Oh, right, thanks.

Comment: Now it only matches if the command is exactly `cd` without any argument.

Comment: Still error-prone (try with `echo cd`); how about `is_cd () { set -- $(history 1); [[ $2 == "cd" ]] && echo is_cd || echo is_not; }`

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this! For this issue I think I'm going with the answer @dan provided. But I have other uses I can apply this to right now, actually.